# Password protect zipkin

Tags: zipkin

I am using zipkin to do distributed tracing of my microservice architecture.

I have created zipkin server by adding zipkin server dependency and @EnableZipkinServer Annotation.

Now is there a way I can add password protection to my zipkin web interface?

Answer (score 0):

The UI cannot be password protected without also password protecting the API endpoints, including the one you would send your spans to.

PS: The `@EnableZipkinServer` annotation has been deprecated